# An object reference is required for the non-static field, method, or property (dataset)

Tags: c#, asp.net, dataset

Why Method can`t send me values from database using dataset?

[Here is example](http://msdn.microsoft.com/pl-pl/library/h71xaeh0.aspx)

Example with error

```
public string dane()
        {
            // Get the DataTable of a DataSet.

            DataTable table = DataSet1.Tables["Products"];
            DataRow[] rows = table.Select();

            string s ="";
            // Print the value one column of each DataRow.
            for (int i = 0; i < rows.Length; i++)
            {
                s += rows[i]["ProductID"] + "  ";
            }

            return s;

        }
```

Error - An object reference is required for the non-static field, method, or property

It`s not possible to find data. (but error is fixed)

```
public string dane()
{
    // Get the DataTable of a DataSet.
    DataSet1 dataSet = new DataSet1();
    DataTable table = dataSet.Tables["Products"];
    DataRow[] rows = table.Select();

    string s ="";
    // Print the value one column of each DataRow.
    for (int i = 0; i < rows.Length; i++)
    {
        s += rows[i]["ProductID"] + "  ";
    }

    return s;

}
```

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Thats because your `DataSet1` class is *probably* not static, though we don't know because you haven't shown us. You cannot reference `Tables` without creating a `DataSet1` object first. I imagine you get the error here:

```
DataTable table = DataSet1.Tables["Products"];
```

And in your second code example, you actually create an instance of `DataSet` which resolves the error.

You can either keep your fix or make `DataSet1` static, though in this case, it doesn't seem that that would be a good solution.

Comment: @Rafael-JuniorMVCDeveloper Have you stepped through your code and verified that `rows` actually contains anything after you do `table.Select()`?

Comment: @Rafael-JuniorMVCDeveloper That's a separate issue. With what you've provided here, I cannot answer that question.

Answer (score 1):

You have no reference to the dataset in the first example. You need to pass this in or make it a global variable.